# php loop through array of objects and assign variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out the value of sessionkey and assign to variable, but I'm confused on how I can go about doing that in php.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [timeout] => 1800
    [lastname] => cloud
    [registered] => false
    [username] => admin
    [firstname] => admin
    [domainid] => d323388a-ab41-11e4-91c4-464e571bcea9
    [userid] => ff5705c6-ab41-11e4-91c4-464e571bcea9
    [type] => 1
    [sessionkey] => DPguBrSBFB7hcdNZAgAyMJIPm4c=
    [account] => admin
)
```

output for var_dump

```
object(stdClass)#5 (10) { ["timeout"]=> string(4) "1800" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "cloud" ["registered"]=> string(5) "false" ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["firstname"]=> string(5) "admin" ["domainid"]=> string(36) "d323388a-ab41-11e4-91c4-464e571bcea9" ["userid"]=> string(36) "ff5705c6-ab41-11e4-91c4-464e571bcea9" ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["sessionkey"]=> string(28) "vzaQz+uVdL/NQQE7eRSimP6FIf4=" ["account"]=> string(5) "admin" }
```

This is what I have tried, but its not working.

```
foreach ($vms as $key => $obj) {
    foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $name => $value) {
        echo "Object mapped to $key has property $name => $value";
    }
}
```

but I keep seeing this in the logs.

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
```

your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe php is interpreting  "$name => $value"  in echo statement as you are trying to access  property "Value" in object "name".try removing "=>" and see if it works

Comment: Where does `$vms` come from and what is its value?

Comment: As @RichardA say, show us dump for `$vms`.